# Reveal multiple selected files in Finder from script

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line

From within a shell script (or, similarly, within a terminal) I want to reveal multiple files in Finder with all named files already selected.

Surprisingly, using `open -R` with multiple arguments fails to achieve this when files share a folder. For example, if I have two files, `/tmp/foo/file1` and `/tmp/foo/file2`, then `open -R /tmp/foo/file1 /tmp/foo/file2` causes a Finder window to open showing `/tmp/foo` but with only `file2` selected, rather than both selected.

Is revealing multiple files within a single folder, with multiple files preselected, programmatically achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derived from an answer by @wch1zpink (since deleted), my first solution was as follows.

in `reveal_files.scpt`:

```
on run argv
  set fileAliases to {}

  repeat with filePath in argv
    copy (POSIX file filePath as alias) to the end of fileAliases
  end repeat

  tell application "Finder" to reveal fileAliases
end run
```

and then `osascript reveal_files.scpt /tmp/foo/file1 /tmp/foo/file2` produces the desired outcome.

My second solution is in Swift via AppKit:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/swift

import AppKit

let args = CommandLine.arguments.dropFirst()
NSWorkspace.shared.activateFileViewerSelecting(args.map {
    URL(fileURLWithPath: $0)
})
```

and for lists of files, xargs(1) may be used e.g.

```
find ~/Downloads -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 reveal_files
```

Comment: I've written a full utility based on the second solution, you can find it at https://github.com/inopinatus/reveal

Answer (score 0):

The following Applescript will also work to reveal multiple files copied and pasted into a focused location in Finder. You can easily modify it to pass a list of filenames to `theFiles` instead of setting it to `the clipboard`, and a specific path to `thePath` instead of having it be set to `(insertion location as alias)` (i.e. the frontmost window/focused location in Finder).

```
tell application "Finder"
    set thePath to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)
    set theFiles to paragraphs of (the clipboard)
    set theOutput to {}
    set theFile to {}
    
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theFiles
        set theFile to POSIX file (thePath & item i of theFiles) as text
        set end of theOutput to theFile as text
    end repeat
    
    reveal theOutput
    activate
    
end tell
--return theOutput
```

I wrote this and use it with a Keyboard Maestro macro when pasting items in Finder because I got tired of losing stuff in folders with a large quantity of files immediately after pasting something into them, needing to mess around with sorting, etc.